# How to prevent alphabetical ordering of rows when converting dataframe to csv?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to convert the following dataframe to a `csv` file using the `to_csv()` function of pandas (`v0.24.0`):

```
             robustness  orseilline  disrupt
             jarkman     woodprint   antennariid
sublinguae   436         47588       60
coupee       994         67199       21
Sauropsida   494         97139       57
metapleural  652         85448       95
sulphuret    667         55142       96
```

The ordering of the rows is important, but the result automatically orders the rows alphabetically:

```
,robustness,orseilline,disrupt
,jarkman,woodprint,antennariid
Sauropsida,436,47588,60
coupee,994,67199,21
metapleural,494,97139,57
sublinguae,652,85448,95
sulphuret,667,55142,96
```

The DataFrame is generated using some code that creates random cells:

```
# 'rows' is predefined by some other generating function
stubs = [random.sample(words.words(), self.n_rows) for x in range(self.n_stubs)]
stubs = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(stubs)
headers = [random.sample(words.words(), self.n_columns) for x in range(self.n_headers)]
headers = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(headers)
table = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, index=stubs, columns=headers)
```

The MultiIndex apparently has some order (named 'codes') that gets disregarded when the DataFrame is converted to a csv. When using `.to_latex()` or `to_html()`, the order is preserved. How to handle this issue?

Comment: The csv I posted was given by `print(df.to_csv())`

Comment: hmmm, so `print (df.head(10))` and `print(df.head(10).to_csv())` are different?

Comment: Correct, those two are different

Comment: what version of Pandas are you using? I think there was a bug in some old version

Comment: Am using 0.24.0

Comment: I'm creating the dataframe using MultiIndex for the columns and the index. That seems to be the problem, as these seem to specify some ordering that is disregarded when saving to csv..

Comment: can you post the part of the code where you create the dataframe?

Comment: Edited the post for that purpose